# Replace values of 0 in Pandas dataframe using mathematical formula involving the previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes as below and I am trying to replace the `0` values from column `Price` in the first one.

The first dataframe looks like this:

| Region | Country | Product | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2016 | 500 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2017 | 400 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2018 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | ABC | 2019 | 450 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2016 | 750 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2017 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2018 | 0 |
| Africa | South Africa | XYZ | 2019 | 890 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2016 | 500 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2017 | 470 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2018 | 0 |
| Asia | Japan | DEF | 2019 | 415 |

It contains price for each type of product for each country for a given year. Some countries have values of `0` for certain years as that data is missing.

The second dataframe contains the average yearly price growth for each region and product and looks like this.

| Region | Product | Average Yearly Price Growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | ABC | 0.043 |
| Africa | DEF | 0.071 |
| Africa | XYZ | 0.0128 |
| Asia | XYZ | 0.05 |
| Asia | ABC | 0.009 |
| Asia | DEF | -0.021 |

The task is to replace all `0` values in the first dataframe with the previous year's value for that particular product in that particular country, plus the average yearly rate increase(or decrease).

As an example, for product `XYZ` in `South Africa` in `2017`, instead of `0` the value should be `750+750*0.0128=759.6`. Where `750` is the previous year value for that product in that country and `0.0128` is the average yearly price growth for that product in Africa (from dataframe 2).

Then for the same product but in 2018, the value should be the previously calculated one, `759.6+759.6*0.0128=769.32`.

Here is the sample data:

```
data1 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 400, 0,450,750,0,0,890,500,470,0,415]}

data2 = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Product': ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],
         'Average Yearly Price Growth': [0.043, 0.071, 0.0128,0.05,0.009,-0.021]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
     if rows['Price']==0:
        try:
                    past_year_value = df[(df['Country']==rows['Country']) & (df['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df['Region']==rows['Region']) & (df['Year']==rows['Year']-1)]['Price'].values[0]
                    df.at[index,'Price'] = past_year_value + past_year_value*df2[(df2['Product']==rows['Product']) & (df2['Region']==rows['Region'])]['Average Yearly Price Growth'].values[0]
        except:
                    pass
```

Try except has been added as It can be the case for the initial year we have a 0 hence no past year to recalculate value

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried applying it but it doesn't change any of the 0 values at all. I have 288 zeroes before running your code and I have 288 after I run it

Comment: Can you remove try except & check for the error message. Might be some small bug

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the row starting with past_year_value. The error is as follows: TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

Comment: I suspect it's because of the .values()[0] but I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: try removing parenthesis from values() & retry. Or post a small dataset snippet. Will revert

Comment: I updated the script with the sample data.

Comment: updated the code, its working fine now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245847/discussion-between-mehul-gupta-and-a-n).